# "Дар речи" Чей это дар ?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Answer (score 3):

Речь - у человека, человек - на Земле, Земля - в солнечной системе, солнечная система - в галактике Млечный путь, галактика Млечный путь - во Вселенной. Где находится Вселенная? Ответив на этот вопрос, вы поймёте откуда у человека такой дар, как речь.

Comment: Вселили, шутка. Куда можно вселить?  Туда, где кое-как жить можно.

Answer (score 2):

Это принадлежащий нам дар - от Бога, либо от природы.

Comment: Бойся Данайцев -дары приносящих.

Answer (score 1):

"Чей" - это "от кого", "у кого" или "кому"? ))
Я так понимаю, что он наш, человеческий. Животные его в целом лишены.
А если по Библии, то речь дана человеку Богом.